# Why `rename` behaves differently whenever I use full path instead current path?

Tags: regular-expression, rename, perl

Ok, I'm [answering a question](https://askubuntu.com/a/350624/169736) where the OP have several repositories in Ubuntu that might be causing a problem installing unrelated software. I recommend disabling the PPA's using a single liner `rename` then follow a series of instructions. Everything fine, and I just leave that question behind as answered.... no. Results that `rename` didn't behave as I'm expecting to:

```
sudo rename s/list/list\.disable/g /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
```

With this I'm expecting rename to look into `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` any file ending in `.list` and replace the `.list` with `.list.disable`. I had another answer with almost the same command but OP never gave feedback, and I'm kind of throwing the theory without testing first. So, it's by my surprise that OP find problems with the line:

```
Can't rename /etc/apt/sources.list.d/iaz-battery-status-quantal.list /etc/apt/sources.list.disable.d/iaz-battery-status-quantal.list.disable: No such file or directory
Can't rename /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ppa-quantal.list /etc/apt/sources.list.disable.d/ubuntu-wine-ppa-quantal.list.disable: No such file or directory
Can't rename /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java-raring.list /etc/apt/sources.list.disable.d/webupd8team-java-raring.list.disable: No such file or directory
```

I get a weird feeling so I test the theory myself, and see the same result. Then, [whenever you get a problem is normally regex, no](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/perl_problems.png)? I changed the regex in so many twisted ways:

- s/.list/.list.disable/g
- s/.list/.list.disable/g
- /list/list.disable/
- other combinations that I don't remember

Well, I decided that regex was not the problem, so I glare to the selector, and change it for `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` and recycle the regex test. No joy. Getting a bit frustrated I do `touch some.list` and apply my command

```
rename s/\.list/\.list\.disable/g *
```

Bingo! Now I feel trolled all over. I fix my answer and continue with my life... no! This is not acceptable. Why? I look up the manual which, for my surprise uses only current path examples. Is this normal? Or is just that the function wasn't implemented? Or I should start to mistrust my theories?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `-n` parameter to run `rename` in a dry-run mode that is very helpful when you want to test your pattern:

```
martin@martin ~ % rename -n s/list/list.disable/g /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list | sed 's/renamed as/\n =>/g'
[...]
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list 
 => /etc/apt/sources.list.disable.d/spotify.list.disable
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list 
 => /etc/apt/sources.list.disable.d/steam.list.disable
[...]
```

The obvious error here is that the pattern `list` matches `sources.list.d`, so you're trying to rename both the folder and its contained files.

Use this pattern instead:

```
rename -n 's/\.list$/.list.disable/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list | sed 's/renamed as/\n =>/g'
[...]
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list 
 => /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list.disable
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list 
 => /etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list.disable
[...]
```

The differences are:

1. Quoting the `.` in the search pattern as `\.` ensures that the dot only matches a real dot, and not any character (that's what an unquoted dot in a regex usually does).
2. The `$` after list means "end of string". It ensures that only the ".list" at the end of the filename matches and will be replaced, not a ".list" that is somewhere else in the path or filename.
3. You don't need to quote the dot in the replacement string; ".list.disable" therefore works without backslashes, because the `.` no longer has special meaning there.
4. Also note that I have quoted the regex in single quotes to prevent the shell from modifying it in any way.

Comment: +1 good use of the diagnostic `-n` switch

Answer (score 1):

The problem is using the global switch `g` when you really should have anchored the pattern instead. As you've written it:

```
s/a/b/g
```

replaces every a with b everywhere in the string. This is causing you to try to rename to paths for which no directory exists. This is also why the problem vanished when you did the operation within the directory so there was only one match to substitute.

I think you might have intended to anchor the pattern

```
s/\.list$/.list.disable/
```

which would have prevented the attempt to move a file into the directory /etc/apt/sources.list.disable.d/ which does not exist (thus you cannot move a file into it).

Comment: I did try without `g`. Same result.

Comment: The note about the `g` flag is just plain wrong, sorry. Not anchoring the pattern is the real issue.

Comment: The g flag caused it to attempt to move files to directories that didn't exist. Not the primary issue, true, but it contributed.